# Postresql Case with complicated calculation in result statement

Tags: postgresql, case

I have a table in a Postgresql database that similar to this one (example only for illustrative purposes)

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FilmName | Donnie Darko |
| FilmYear | 1002 |
| Test1 | 101 |
| Test2 | 202 |
| Test3 | 303 |
| Test4 | 404 |

I need a query that does something like this

```
IF (FilmName = Donnie Darko) THEN Value(Test1) + Value(Test2)
IF (FilmName = Layer Cake) THEN Value(Test3)/ Value(Test4)
```

With **Value(Test1)** being 101 and so on. It is important, the the expression behind the **THEN** is a dynamic reference to a line in the same table, in which the value of the **Property** column in preconfigured. In other words, It shall look for the Value in the **Value** column for the line in which the Value of the **Property** column is "Test1" and so on.

I have been experimenting **CASE** but I cant seem to make sense of it.

One more important fact: The tool I am using forces a **SELECT** around the query that I come up with (kind of nests it). In case the Query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A
```

The program automatically makes it.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLE A) AS Query
```

I guess to avoid SQL injections. So as a second boundary conditions, the solution must be able to be put inside the **FROM** expression of an outer query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) You need a new tool for creating the queries. My suggestion [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). 2) `CASE FilmName = Donnie Darko THEN (select value from A where property = 'Test1') + (select value from A where property = 'Test2') end ...`.

Comment: Please elaborate, how can FilmName = 'Donnie Darko' when FilmName is the value in the column "parameter"?

Comment: This looks like the [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), just with the entity missing? When you say "*a dynamic reference to a line in the same table*", does that mean you are having multiple tables?

Comment: Copy and paste error from your example. New version `CASE property = 'FilmName'  and value = 'Donnie Darko' THEN (select value from A where property = 'Test1') + (select value from A where property = 'Test2') end ...`